# How to check if a thread is sleeping?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

Is there any way to check if a given thread is sleeping?

Comment: Dare I ask why do you need this information?

Comment: is the Thread.sleep() called from your code. on knowing thread is sleeping what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call [`Thread.getState()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29) on and check if the state is [`TIMED_WAITING`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING).

Note, however that `TIMED_WAITING` doesn't necessarily mean that the thread called [`sleep()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29), it could also be waiting in a [`Object.wait(long)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) call or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an ugly hack to check if the other thread is sleeping (calling `Thread.sleep`):

```
public static boolean isSleeping(Thread t) {
    StackTraceElement[] ste = t.getStackTrace();

    return ste.length > 0
        && ste[0].getClassName().equals("java.lang.Thread")
        && ste[0].getMethodName().equals("sleep");
}
```

Comment: What is ParkSupport and Unsafe.park?

Comment: doh I always mistake "java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport" with "ParkSupport"; the impl, itself, is in sun.misc.Unsafe.park

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way but you could change a variable when a thread goes to sleep and check that variable if the thread is sleeping or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own **sleep** method which records the **Thread's ID** to a **global variable** and use it as reference for sleeping thread.

There's no other way you can tell if a thread is precisely sleeping.

Hope **the three links** below help:

- [States](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/states.html)
- [Java Doc 1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)
- [Java Doc 2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)

Answer (score 0):

i didn't actually did it , but there's an  [ThreadMXBean Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadInfo%28long%29) for getting thread Info

which returns [ThreadInfo Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html), there you might get something with getWaitedTime method.