# How can I sleep one thread while the other thread is running in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

The `sleep` method in Java allows us to stop a thread in execution. If there are two threads running and I forcefully `sleep` one thread then the other thread also sleeps.

I created two threads, but when I apply the `sleep` method for one thread while the other thread is running, both threads shows me false as a result for `isAlive` method

Q1) Why does that happen?

Q2) What will happen when I call the `isAlive` method after a specific thread is started, and it shows false?

Q3) What is the difference between `Thread.sleep()` and `thread.sleep()` where `thread` is an instance of the `Thread` class.

This is some sample code for the problem

```java
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable task = ()-> System.out.println("Hello");

        Thread thread =  new Thread(task);
        Thread thread1 =  new  Thread(task);


        thread.start();
        System.out.println(thread.isAlive());
        System.out.println(thread1.isAlive());

        thread1.start();
        System.out.println(thread.isAlive());
        System.out.println(thread1.isAlive());

        thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(thread.isAlive());
        System.out.println(thread1.isAlive());
    }
}
```

actual result:

```
true
false
Hello
true
true
Hello
false
false
```

expected result

```
true
false
Hello
true
true
Hello
false
true
```

Comment: With `isAlive`: `Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.`(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive--) In your case your threads are done at 3rd call of `isAlive`.

Comment: "if I force to sleep one thread then the other thread will also be sleep" no, it won't

Comment: I just want to sleep the first thread, while the other one is working. Here i put the sleep method on the "thread", but why the "thread1" is false

Comment: With `Thread.sleep()` you put on sleep current thread(thread which execute `Thread.sleep()`) and with `thread.sleep()` put on sleep the thread which represent variable `thread`.

Comment: @HashanMahesh Thats what you do. You put on sleep first thread. But it's useless because the thread is already done(cause `isAlive` returns false). To check the state of an thread read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336332/9011164

Comment: @KunLun Yeah, I understood. thank you this is my first StackOverflow question, I got very quick responses..Such a beautiful platform this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no instance method `Thread#sleep(long)`. In fact, you call the static method that sets the calling thread to sleeping state.(see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)))

As @Kayaman sais, within this time, both threads finish, which causes your result.

Also, you should be aware that you cannot predict Threads, because they are very platform dependent and handled different on multiple Systems.

Instead, you can use the instance method `Thread.join()` if you want to wait until a Thread finished.

Comment: ...after which the other threads have finished, and neither of them are alive anymore.

Comment: I've added this.

Comment: Re, "...sets the _current thread_ to sleeping..." IMO the phrase "current thread" is very confusing to newbies. Which thread is the "current thread" on a system that has eight CPUs, and all of them are busy? The name `current_thread` made sense when you saw it in the source code for an operating system that was only ever meant to run on a single-CPU host, but it doesn't make sense any more.  IMO, we should now say, "the caller" or "the calling thread" instead.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.sleep(long seconds) or 'wait()'.
But if you want to wait until the threads finish the jobs. You can use 'thread.join' it's an instance method.

Comment: What you say is true, but it is not the answer to the OP's question. The OP wants to know how one thread can force a _different_ thread to sleep, and the answer is, "Can't do that. That's now how threads work."